# Query Nested DynamoDB Attributes using c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, dynamodb-queries

In the below example ConsumerID is Range Key & RetailerID is Sort Key. Besides this, I want to query the JSON using a specific item_id (ex: item_id = "3dc8dbfa-fc12-4fd1-8485-be768b2c464d"). Is this possible with just query & not use Scan operation in DynamoDB?

```
{
"ConsumerID":"DHDHDHDHD",
"RetailerID":"szdfdzzf",  
"ConsumerInfo": {
  "IsReferred": 1,
  "IsSecReceipt": "N",
  "IsSplitLimit": 0,
  "ReceiptStatus": "Y",
  "ReferralStatus": "Inprogress",
  "SplitStatus": "Open",
  "TempID2": null,
  "TempID3": null,
  "TempID4": null,
  "itemMapping": 
  [
   {
    "issubscribed": 0,
    "ratingstatus": "Open",
    "internal_id": null,
    "isratinglimit": 0,
    "item_id": "79214470-b639-4edd-9218-abee1755708e",
    "subscribestatus": "Open"
   },
   {
    "issubscribed": 0,
    "ratingstatus": "Open",
    "internal_id": null,
    "isratinglimit": 0,
    "item_id": "3dc8dbfa-fc12-4fd1-8485-be768b2c464d",
    "subscribestatus": "Open"
   }
   ]
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?